# Change the size of UIButton’s imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I am working on a subclass of `UIButton`, let’s call it `MyButton`. In most cases, buttons of this subclass will have both image and title.

I am having troubles configuring `MyButton`’s `imageView` size. **The goal is to limit the size of the image, so that larger images are resized and fit into a 32-by-32 square.**

*For testing purposes, I added a 128-by-128-pixel image, and set `imageView`’s `backgroundColor` to `green`.*

Below is what the button looked like when I added the image. Both the `imageView` and its `image` had the size of 128 by 128 pixels.

[image: Button with the original-size image]

After I overrode `MyButton`’s `intrinsicContentSize` with `CGSize(width: 160, height: 50)` and set the button’s `imageView`’s `contentMode` to `.scaleAspectFit`, the `imageView` resized, but only in height—it’s still 128 pixels wide, which causes the button’s title to truncate.

[image: Button with reduced height but original width]

I’ve seen a lot of articles on how to resize the `image` inside the `imageView` using `imageEdgeInsets`. **This is not what I am looking for** since in all those articles the `imageView` preserves its size and only adds padding around the image.

Changing the `imageView`’s `frame` or `bounds` produces no result.

Any thoughts on how I can resize the button’s `imageView`?

Answer (score 9):

```
let customButtonImage = MyButton.currentImage
```

now you have your button image resize it using @jay's extension for resizing image

```
let newimage = customButtonImage. resizedImage(size:requiredSize)
```

Reset image to button

```
self.setImage(newimage, for: .normal)   //normal or what state your want
```

@jays extension

```
  extension UIImage
{
    func resizedImage(Size sizeImage: CGSize) -> UIImage?
    {
        let frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: sizeImage.width, height: sizeImage.height))
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, false, 0)
        self.draw(in: frame)
        let resizedImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        return resizedImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the image and then ad to button's image. Below you can find resize image code.

```
extension UIImage
{
    func resizedImage(Size sizeImage: CGSize) -> UIImage?
    {
        let frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: sizeImage.width, height: sizeImage.height))
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, false, 0)
        self.draw(in: frame)
        let resizedImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        return resizedImage
    }
}
```

Button ui extension.

```
@IBInspectable var sizeImage: CGSize {
    get {
        return self.imageView?.image?.size ?? CGSize.zero
    }
    set {
        if let image = self.imageView?.image {
            let imgUpdate = image.resizedImage(Size: newValue)
            self.setImage(imgUpdate, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```